# Icons mobile view RWD the,

Tags: mobile

I am having a little issue with my website, it's responsive site, when viewed in smaller screens the checkout icon or search icon shows in 3 lines. I must have done something wrong, can someone point me in the right direction of what file could be causing this.

**My website uses magentos latest default theme.**

Comment: It's all about css. You must edit css file to get what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thank-You, I really cant see why its doing it! Its very strange why its only showing 3 lines

Comment: can you give your url to have a look? or add some screen shots.

Comment: Sorry, it would of helped if I added it! https://sssextreme.com

Comment: Looking at the link, it's fine to me. Menu, Search, Cart are scaled to small size to fit in responsive screen size. Sorry if I am not understanding your question.

Comment: Sorry, don't think I worded it very well. The icon for the cart and my account section shows an icon with 3 lines instead of the cart icon or the person icon

Answer (score 0):

Alright, first of all this is css question.

You will need to edit your `skin/frontend/rwd/default/css/styles.css` file.
Go to line `3437` and add following code below that line:

```
.skip-car .icon{background-position: left -95px;}
```

Remember above line of code must be after `.skip-link .icon {  margin-right: 3px;}`

Hope this will help.